# Using @Resource or @Autowired to prevent @Cacheable method from being ignored when called from the same class

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis, spring-cache

I fixed the caching problem using @Resource or @Autowired, but is this correct? What problems can it cause?

```
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AuthClientService {
    
    @Resource or @Autowired
    private AuthClientService authClientService;

    private final AuthenticationClient authenticationClient;

    @Cacheable(value = "appCache", key = "#code")
    public String findUserTypeByCode(String code) {
        return authenticationClient.findUserTypeByCode(code).getData();
    }

    public String getUserType() {
        return authClientService.findUserTypeByCode(ContextHolder.getCurrentContext().getCustomContext().getTypeCode());
    }
}
```

Does it cost anything to use it this way?